# (A join B) join (C join D)

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to make specific order of JOINs

```
SELECT *
FROM (lives_in as t1 NATURAL JOIN preferences p1) l1
JOIN (lives_in t2 NATURAL JOIN preferences p2) l2
ON l1.dormid = l2.dormid
```

Returns an error.

Anyone can help? Thanks a lot!

Comment: Please put create table syntax of your tables.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your aliased queries are missing a `SELECT` clause, so try this:

```
SELECT *
FROM (
    select * -- added this
    FROM lives_in as t1
    NATURAL JOIN preferences p1) l1
JOIN (
    select * -- added this
    FROM lives_in t2
    NATURAL JOIN preferences p2) l2
ON l1.dormid = l2.dormid
```

Answer (score 1):

The order of joins doesn't matter for the results. You probably want something like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM lives_in t1 
NATURAL JOIN preferences p1 ON p1.some_id = t1.id
NATURAL JOIN preferences p2 ON p2.some_id = t1.id
```

Also, most people call it an INNER JOIN, not a NATURAL JOIN, btw.

Comment: Btw, I don't know how the preference and lives_in tables are related (my assumption is via `some_id` in common), but you need to define that relationship otherwise the JOIN is meaningless.

Comment: A natural join is an inner join, but where the join condition is *implied* by matching on all like-named columns. Basically a bug-fest waiting to happen.

Answer (score 1):

Hope it will helpful.

```
SELECT *
FROM (
select * from lives_in as t1 NATURAL JOIN preferences p1
) l1
JOIN (
select * from lives_in t2 NATURAL JOIN preferences p2
) l2
ON l1.dormid = l2.dormid
```